# Configuring arbitrary objects in Gradle

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

build.gradle:

```
task configure << {
    pos = new java.text.FieldPosition(10)
    // Apply the script
    apply from: 'other.gradle', to: pos
    println pos.beginIndex
    println pos.endIndex
}
```

other.gradle:

```
beginIndex = 1;
endIndex = 5;
```

Command line:

```
gradle -q configure
```

The above piece of code is from [Chapter 14](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/tutorial_this_and_that.html#N10C7E) of the Gradle User Guide.
I am confused about "pos" and hence could not understand the whole piece of code. I thought it is an object, instead of project.

Any clarifications with this is appreciated.

Thanks,
Prithula

Comment: Please fix the code formatting, and include a reference to where you found this in the Gradle documentation.

Comment: The snippet is from Gradle User docs Chapter 14 (http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/tutorial_this_and_that.html) Section 14.4. Configuring arbitrary objects.

Comment: It is section 14.5. Apologies for the typo.

Comment: `def pos = ...` would be cleaner code. Does this answer your question? Note that this about configuring arbitrary objects *using a script*, which is a supported but rarely used feature.

Comment: thanks Peter for reply. even if it is declared with def, but to me it looks like it is an object, rather than a project. Also does it matter where we put the "apply from" in a build.gradle, as the tasks defined in the external file will be executed when they are called directly or via any dependent tasks. Please let me know if my understanding is wrong?

Comment: It is an object. (Why do you think it's a project?) I don't understand your second question. Perhaps create a new post for that.

Answer (score 0):

`pos` is a `FieldPosition` **object**. Your code snippet is just initializing the object with values from another file. You could have initialized it like this:

```
def pos = new java.text.FieldPosition(10)
pos.beginIndex = 1
pos.endIndex = 5
```

but instead the snippet:

```
apply from: 'other.gradle', to: pos
```

reads the values from `beginIndex` and `endIndex` from `other.gradle` and applies those field settings to the `pos` object.

Answer (score 0):

well,you forget to add 'def' before pos,you should define it by "def pos" to make a pos as local variable.apply 'to' can be used to configure objects other than this object.so by apply a script to pos, you can set the script properties to pos's properties.
the complete code is like below:

in build.gradle

```
task configure <<{
 def pos = new java.text.FieldPosition(10)
 apply from: 'other.gradle',to: pos
 println pos.beginIndex
 println pos.endIndex
}
```

in other.gradle

```
beginIndex = 1
endIndex = 5
```